# Какая сетка у макета?

Tags: javascript, html, css, design

Макет есть только в зеплине. На стандартную сетку бутстрапа в 12 колонок не подходит. Блоки не совпадают.
Есть ли смысл попробовать изменить количество колонок/их ширину и отступы? 
Какие способы есть чтобы это подобрать?

Или вообще верстать без сетки если ее нет в макете?
[image: скрин макета]

[image: скрин 2]

Comment: Используйте flexbox

Comment: А вы уверены, что макет вообще по сетке построен? В web-версии zeplin в сайдбаре на вкладке info(открыта по умолчанию) включите флажок `grids`. Мне недавно попался макет с вроде бы бутстраповской сеткой, но остступы между колонками не 30px, а 20. А так согласен с @soledar10 , `flexbox` в помощь.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров спасибо за помощь. Добавил скрин с сеткой, в ней 7 колонок, некоторые блоки  не совпадают с сеткой. Заказчик настаивает на бутстрапе. Как на ваш взгляд это возможно реализовать с помощью бутстрапа?

Comment: @Max , Если заказчик не настаивает на `Pixel Perfect` - приблизительно вписать в бутстраповскую сетку. Ни или делать свои блоки внутри бутстраповских контейнеров.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров Pixel Perfect одно из требований к сожалению) свои блоки внутри бутстраповских контейнеров, это означает без деления на колонки? 
Можно ли в моем случае собрать кастомную сетку с 7ю колонками и использовать ее? Или так не делают?

Comment: @Max , так тут и в 7-ми колоночную не всё вписывается. Остаётся руками, а bootstrap так, чтобы был.

Comment: А что вам мешает создать на бутсрап 7 колоночную сетку с нужными отступами? Исходя из скриншота у вас часть елементов будет по сетке, а часть нет.